# Passing an object to a class through another class

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I have a tableview controller class, a tableviewcell subclass and a uibutton subclass.
I am creating an instance of the unbutton subclass in the tableviewcell subclass and initialize a button in a specific cell position. 
Then I am using this cell in the tableview controller class. Also I am trying to add an IBAction to the button. But it can't recognize the object of the uibutton subclass while everything else works fine. What am I doing wrong in the declaration?

**tableviewcell.m**

```
#import "tableviewcell.h"
#import "CustomCheckButton.h"

    CustomCheckButton *starbtn = [[CustomCheckButton alloc] init];;


            starbtn = [[CustomCheckButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(243,0, 30, 30)];
```

**tableviewcontroller.m**

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath object startbtn won't be recognized:

```
#import "ScannedProductControllerViewController.h"
#import "imageCellCell.h"


    tableviewcell*firstRowCell = (tableviewcell *)cell;


    [firstRowCell.prodimage  setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"test1.jpg"]];
    [firstRowCell.label1 setText:@"17.5"];
    [firstRowCell.label2 setText:@"Score"];

    [firstRowCell.basket  setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Basket.jpg"]];

    // reference of the home button to the buttonclick method

    [firstRowCell.homebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // reference of the favorites button to the buttonclick method

    [firstRowCell.starbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickFavButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**CustomCheckButton.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCheckButton : UIButton {
    BOOL    _checked;
}

@property (nonatomic, setter = setChecked:) BOOL checked;

-(void) setChecked:(BOOL) check;

@end
```

Comment: Have you tried exposing it as a property?

Comment: I have tried to expose it as a property but for some reason it does not recognize it. And @holex trust me I ve searched a lot but can't make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) CustomCheckButton *startButton;
@end

@implementation TableViewCell
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    self.startButton = [[CustomCheckButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(243,0, 30, 30)];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.startButton];
}
@end
```

Comment: I have tried to declare it as property, but it says unknown type name

Comment: Did you import the header file for that class?

Comment: in the .m file yes. But it does not recognize the name in the property at the .h file

Comment: You need to either forward declare the class in the header or just import the class in the header.

Comment: Something must be stuck cause it does not recognize it. I will try restart or something. Thanks anyway

Comment: Since I restarted it recognized it. Adding your code however won't show up the button in the interface.

Comment: Are you adding it as a subview? Is the button in a xib or storyboard? One of those two should be yes.

Answer (score 0):

First, why don't you create your cells in the storyboard as a prototype cell or inside of a XIB file.

Then, create an IBAction to the button and respond to it in the cell. Finally, make a protocol for your cell that will inform the delegate when the button is tapped. You can then setup your table view controller as the delegate of the cells and respond to the button tapped. If you need to determine which cell you're working with, you can even pass the cell as a parameter of one of the protocol's methods you use.

Comment: Sorry but I want a solution programmatically